# How can I stop my program from going back to a function that should be finished executing?

Tags: c++, function

I am pretty new to coding, and I have written a program that is supposed to ask the user for the number of employees, their absent days, and then calculate the average number of absent days. However, it asks for the number of employees a second time after already providing the program with the # of employees and their absent days. I've looked over it and don't understand why it is doing this. I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int numEmployees();
int daysAbsent(int);
double averageAbsent(int, int);

void main()
{
    cout << "The average of absence days is: " << averageAbsent(numEmployees(), daysAbsent(numEmployees()));
}

int numEmployees()
{
    static int employees;
    cout << "Enter the number of employees: ";
    cin >> employees;

    while (employees < 1)
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1: \n";
        cin >> employees;
    }

    return employees;
}

int daysAbsent(int employees)
{
    int sumDays = 0;
    int employeeAbsent;

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= employees; counter++)
    {
        cout << "How many days was employee no. " << counter << " absent?\n";
        cin >> employeeAbsent;

        while (employeeAbsent < 0)
        {
            cout << "Please enter a positive value: \n";
            cin >> employeeAbsent;
        }

        sumDays += employeeAbsent;
    }

    return sumDays;
}

double averageAbsent(int employees, int sumDays)
{
    double average = (double)sumDays / employees;
    return average;
}
```

Comment: The main function should return an `int`. You call the function twice, and you wonder why it executes twice? `averageAbsent(numEmployees(), daysAbsent(numEmployees()))` - this is the relevant code.

Comment: `main` calls `numEmployees()` twice, so of course you are prompted for input twice.

Comment: Voting to close as typo, there is no mystery as to why the function is executed twice.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
averageAbsent(numEmployees(), daysAbsent(numEmployees())
```

This says to:

- Call `numEmployees` so the value it returns can be passed to `averageAbsent`
- Call `numEmployees` so the value it returns can be passed to `daysAbsent`

If you want to use a value more than once, store it in a variable.

Comment: I suppose this is how you get the big points, but this question should be closed as a typo.

Comment: I think its a judgment call. Maybe something that is not obvious to a new programmer.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry if this seemed like a silly question. I am just recently learning how to use functions. What would be the correct way to call it, because when I remove the second numEmployees(), I get a message saying there are too few arguments? I appreciate the responses.

Comment: Call the `numEmployees()` and save its value in a variable first. Then use that variable when you call averageAbsent()

Comment: Got it. Thanks everyone!